# weak derivatives on open subset implies weak derivatives on whole set

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, weak-derivatives

Let $V' \subset V\subset U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be bounded open sets such that $\overline{V'} \subset V$ and $f\in W^{m,p}(V,\mathbb{R})$ such that $f|_{V \backslash V'} \equiv 0$. Do we have then that $f \in W^{m,p}(U,\mathbb{R})$? Do the weak derivatives of $f$ on $U$ even exist? By $W^{m,p}(V,\mathbb{R})$ I denote the Sobolev space of functions with derivative up to $m$ to belong in $L^{p}$.

Comment: You can have $V^\prime = V$ with your hypotheses. Then it is not true. Perhaps you mean $V^\prime \Subset V$ ?

Comment: Yes, you are right I actually mean $\overline{V'} \subset V$. Is it then true? If yes, why?

Comment: In your question, you do not assume anything on the behaviour of $f$ on $U \setminus V$. What about $f = 0$ on $V$ and $f = 1$ on $U \setminus V$? Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\overline{V^\prime} \subset V$, there is a $C^\infty$ function $\psi$ such that $\text{supp}(\psi)\subset V$ and $\psi = 1$ on an open set containing $\overline{V^\prime}$. Then $f = f \psi$ and I think it becomes easy to prove that $f\in W^{m, p}(U, \mathbb{R})$.

If $T$ is a distribution in $V$ with support in $\overline{V^\prime}$, it can be viewed as a distribution in $U$ by defining for $\phi\in C^\infty_0(U)$
$$\langle T, \phi\rangle = \langle T, \psi\phi\rangle$$
because $\psi\phi\in C^\infty_0(V)$. Then
$$\langle \partial^\alpha T, \phi\rangle = \langle \partial^\alpha T, \psi\phi\rangle = \langle T, (-1)^{|\alpha|} \partial^\alpha(\psi \phi)\rangle = \langle T, (-1)^{|\alpha|} \psi\partial^\alpha(\phi)\rangle$$
because the derivatives of $\psi$ vanish in a neighborhood of $\text{supp}(T)$

Comment: Why do then the weak derivatives of $f$ on $U$ exist ?

Comment: For $\phi \in C^{\infty}_{c}(U)$ how does on compote the integral $\int_{U} f(x) \phi ' (x) dx = \int_{U} \psi (x) f(x) \phi ' (x) dx = ... $?

Comment: See my edit  about distributions.

Comment: Is this still true if $f|_{V\backslash V'} \equiv 0 $ almost everywhere?

Comment: Yes because $L^p$ functions are seen as distributions via the Lebesgue integral, which doesn't make a difference between 0 and "0 almost everywhere".